# In EC2, is the pricing of a 64bit Micro server the same as 32bit Micro server?

Tags: amazon-ec2

It doesn't really say it specifically on their page.

Comment: Have you considered asking Amazon?

Answer (score 1):

I'll save you the trouble of looking it up :)
Yes it is. (I currently run both 32bit and 64bit and can confirm they charge the same for both)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to call them. Unless you happen to have one of their sales people look at your question on here thats going to be your best bet. Even if someone does claim to work there I'd take it with a grain of salt and call anyway.